# jQuery .click() with double output

Tags: jquery, logging, console, output

I use jquery on my website, i need onclick event, my code look so:

```
<ul>
<li><label id="myLbl"><span class="icon"></span></label></li>
</ul>
```

and jQuery part:

```
$('ul.checkboxlist li label').on('click', function() {
        var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).children('span.checkboxbg').toggleClass('checkboxbgarrow');
        console.log('Selected elementID: ' + currentId);
    }
);
```

});

If i click on the label, then i get in the console the same id 2 times, how can i make it true to 1 click, so i see in console the same outptu 2 times...

Comment: I don't understand the question :)

Comment: "If i click on the label, then i get in the console the same id 2 times, how can i make it true to 1 click, so i see in console the same outptu 2 times..." Could you explain?

Comment: use runat server for label control. It will create two different ids

Comment: @JagzW: What on Earth are you talking about?

Comment: have you use the right selector for for selecting the element

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue.  For me it shows only one time: http://jsfiddle.net/PHJqp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/).
  This method will remove event attached with .on().